# Prove that $S=\{f(\pi^5):f(x)\in \Bbb Q[x]\}$ is not a sub field of $\Bbb C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Put $S=\{f(\pi^5):f(x)\in \Bbb Q[x]\}$. Prove that $S$ is not a subfield of $\Bbb C$.

My attempt at a solution by contradiction, consider the 5th subfield axiom if 
$a$ has an inverse $b$ then $ab=1$ so now let $a=f(\pi^5)$ and $b=g(\pi^5)$ then $ab=f(\pi^5)g(\pi^5)=1$ but we know that $f(\pi^5)\ne 1$ as it is transcendent thus a contradiction

is this right? and if not can anyone guide me from here?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with $s=f(\pi^5)$ (an element) to be a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$? From what you did, you seem to prove that $f(\pi^5)$ does not have an inverse in $\mathbb{C}$, but I am afraid that is simply wrong: if $f(x)=a^nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$, then $f(\pi^5)=a^n\pi^{5n}+\cdots+a_1\pi^5+a_0$, and certainly $f(\pi^5)\cdot \left(\dfrac{1}{a^n\pi^{5n}+\cdots+a_1\pi^5+a_0}\right)=1$

Comment: it just says in the question show that s = the set above is not a subfield of C

Comment: and you may assume pi is transcendental, the part before this was to show that f(pi^5) is transcendental

Comment: You have to edit adding that the constant polynomials are discarded. If not you can add all number you need, for example if $f(x)=1$ then $f(\pi^5)=1$

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post.

Comment: If you would like to ask a new question, please, [ask a new question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @Alwayslearning Please *stop* re-vandalizing your question.

Comment: Can you delete this question?

Comment: If you get the attention of a moderator and come up with a *solid* reason why the question needs to be deleted, they may be able to do so.

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track but you should argue as follows:

Let $a=\pi^5$. Then $a\in S$ and $a\ne0$.
If there existed $b \in S$ such that $ab=1$, then we'd have $b=g(\pi^5)$ and $\pi^5g(\pi^5)=1$, which contradicts the fact that $\pi$ is transcendental because we'd have $h(\pi)=0$ for $h(x)=x^5g(x^5)-1 \in \mathbb Q[x]$, with $h \ne 0$.

Thus $a=\pi^5$ is an element of $S$ that does not have an inverse in $S$ and so $S$ is not a field.

Comment: how do we know b=g(pi^5) and should a not be f(pi^5)

Comment: ? if you could provide a little more information it would help a lot , thanks

Comment: The proof he provided still holds if it happens that $f({\pi}^5)=g({\pi}^5)=a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever be $f(x)\in \Bbb Q[x]$, you have $f(\pi^5)$ is a trascendental number because if not $\pi^5$ would be algebraic. Then all the elements of $S$ being trascendental,  the number $1\notin S$ i.e. $S$ has not the identity for the group multiplicative hence can not be a field.

Comment: The constant polynomial $f=1$ gives $1 \in S$.

Comment: Can someone delete this post as it just gives the answer, i only wanted to check if my working was correct,thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be a complex number. The map
$$
e_a\colon\mathbb{Q}[x]\to \mathbb{C},\qquad
e_a(f)=f(a)
$$
is a ring homomorphism and its image is $S_a=\{f(a):f\in\mathbb{Q}[x]\}$, so $S_a$ is a subring of $\mathbb{C}$. Your case is $a=\pi^5$.

If $a$ is transcendental, then $\ker e_a=\{0\}$, so the homomorphism is injective and $S_a\cong\mathbb{Q}[x]$ as rings. Since $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is not a field, neither $S_a$ is.

If $a$ is transcendental, then all of its powers $a^n$, with $n>0$ are transcendental. Indeed, if $g(a^n)=0$ for a nonzero polynomial $g\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$, we would have a nonzero polynomial $g_0\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with $g_0(a)=0$. So $\pi^5$ is transcendental, because $\pi$ is.